# ajax unable to find url c# method

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am unable to find the url in my ajax call. Below is the Html code

```
<div class='replyDiv1' id='sendmail_form'>
 <h2>Reply</h2>
 <label>Subject:</label><span class='replySubject'>Reply: #=MessageSubject#</span><br />
 <label class='datereply'>Date:</label><span class='replytime'></span><br /> 
 <label>To:</label><span>#=MailFrom#</span><br />
 <label class='claimIDReply'>Claim:</label><span>#=ClaimId#</span>
 <label>Message:</label><br /><textarea rows='8' style='width:80%;' class='replymessage' placeholder='Reply Here'></textarea><br /><br />
 <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick='button1()' id='sendReply'>Send</button><br /><br /><span id='msg' style='color:red;'/>    
</div>
```

Here is the JavaScript Ajax Code, this is inside the View

```
var dataObject1 = JSON.stringify({
        'MailTo': from,
        'MailFrom': to,
        'ClaimId': claimID,
        'CreateDate': time,
        'MessageBody': newMessage,
        'MessageSubject': subject,
    });
$.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        datatype: "json",
        url: '@Url.Action("SendReply1", "MCenterController")',
        data: {},
        cache: false,
        //contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("Fail");
        },
    });
```

Below is the C# method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendReply1()
  {
   return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

When I debug the code in Chrome, I get the error that MCenterController/SendReply1 is not found and the ajax call fails. SendReply1 is the name of the method and MCenterController is the name of the controller.
I need the button to refresh the current page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried to hit your endpoint manually using for instance Postman? making a POST request to your endpoint should hit your C# method.

Comment: Where is the ajax? is it in the view or a separate js file. Also, how is the ajax being told about your razor code?

Comment: @Mark I have not tried that. How would I do that?

Comment: @SimonPrice the ajax is inside the view

Comment: append [HttpGet] to your action and use your browser to point to your url OR use postman https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop (or equivalent tool)

Comment: Are you performing the AJAX call from a view returned by a different controller than MCenterController?